# Selector throwing DOMException but working in console - Tailwind class selector

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS alongsid vanilla JS and I'm trying to get some specific nodes via a built selector. Problem : the selector is marked as invalid when the code executed by the browser (bundled in Webpack) but I can make it work in the web console.

[DOMException thrown by code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC4Y8.png)

Here is a reproductible sample; the problems seems to be around the `w-2/4` containing a `/` so I'm escaping it to make it like `\\/`. Taking any idea to fix this ...

```js
const prefix = '.';
const width = 'w-2/4';
const rounded = 'rounded';

const selector = prefix + width + prefix + rounded;
parsed = selector.replace('/', '\\\\/');

console.log(parsed);

const matches = document.querySelectorAll('.w-2\\/4.rounded');
console.log(matches);

const broken = document.querySelectorAll(parsed);
console.log(broken);
```

```html
<h3 class="inline-block statlib-kpi-value text-2xl h-4 bg-blue-400 rounded w-2/4 "></h3>
```

Answered by @biberman, thanks to him.

Comment: i think the problem is that here are 4 backslashes ```parsed = selector.replace('/', '\\\\/');``` it should be just two...

Comment: Yes, it's that simple ! I had problems while using only two backslashes so it was a remaining attempt to "escape" the backslashes ... thanks a lot.

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer. @Falkettin0 Please mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that here are 4 backslashes `parsed = selector.replace('/', '\\\\/');` it should be just two...

**Working example:**

```js
const prefix = '.';
const width = 'w-2/4';
const rounded = 'rounded';

const selector = prefix + width + prefix + rounded;
parsed = selector.replace('/', '\\/');

console.log(parsed);

const matches = document.querySelectorAll('.w-2\\/4.rounded');
console.log(matches);

const broken = document.querySelectorAll(parsed);
console.log(broken);
```

```html
<h3 class="inline-block statlib-kpi-value text-2xl h-4 bg-blue-400 rounded w-2/4 "></h3>
```